# I have codependent headers in C which is giving me errors. How can I remove it?

Tags: c++, c, header

The tree.h file:

```
#ifndef tree
#define tree

#include "common.h"
#include "set.h"

/*Tree Structure*/
typedef struct
{
    Set *set;
    unsigned int setLength;
    int vertexLength;
    int *vertex;
    int idle;
    int parent;
    int level;
    int numberOfChildren;
} TreeNode;

typedef struct
{
    TreeNode* node;
    int nodeLength;
    int height;
} Tree;

Tree* fill_tree(char *filename, int worldSize, int rank);
int get_number_of_leaves(Tree *tree);
TreeNode get_tree_node(int index, Tree* tree);
TreeNode* get_tree_nodes(Tree* tree);
int get_tree_nodes_length(Tree* tree);
void compute_level(int u, Tree* tree);
void print_tree(Tree* tree);
int get_max_level(Tree* tree);
int* create_task_list(Tree* tree, int* taskListLength, int rank);
int* map(int* taskList, int taskListLength, int* mapLength, int rank);
void generate_combination_sets(Tree* tree, int nodePerProcess, int rank);

#endif
```

The set.h file:

```
#ifndef set
#define set

#include "common.h"
#include "tree.h"

/*Tree Structure*/
typedef struct
{
    int combinationLength;
    int* combination;
} Set;

Set* generate_subsets(int* vertex, int vertexLength, unsigned int pow_set_size, int rank);
Set* match(Set* parent, unsigned int parentLength, Set* child, unsigned int childLength, TreeNode childNode, TreeNode parentNode, unsigned int* solutionLength, Graph* g, int rank);
int* union_operation(int* parenteCombination, int parentCombinationLength, int* childCombination, int childCombinationLength, unsigned int* mergedLength, int rank);
int not_in_solution(Set* solution, int solutionLength , int* merged, unsigned int mergedLength);
void print_set(Set set);

#endif
```

The common.h file:

```
#ifndef common
#define common

// Libraries

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include "graph.h"
#define true 1
#define false 0
#endif
```

I have errors that the tree and the set header files are codependent, and the compiler is giving me an error that set is not found in tree.h and likewise for set. Should I include all the fiels in the common.h file?

Comment: Which of the two tagged programming languages are you _actually_ using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forward declarations when you need to reference the struct in another header file, the header does not need to know the details of the struct, try this in `tree.h`:

```
 #ifndef tree
 #define tree

 #include "common.h"
 // #include "set.h"  <-- don't include set.h

 typedef struct Set Set;

 /*Tree Structure*/
 typedef struct
 {
     Set *set;
     unsigned int setLength;
     int vertexLength;
     ...
 } TreeNode;
```

in `set.h`:

```
typedef struct Set Set;
struct Set
{
    int combinationLength;
    int* combination;
} Set;
```

Comment: But it gave me a warning because I'm using a method found in set.h

Comment: @MohamadYassine what's the warning?

Comment: Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast. I'm using generate_subsets method

Comment: Is it the first argument? it is expacting a pointer to integer, not a integer.

Comment: And also this warning implicit declaration of function 'generate_subset'

Comment: That means you should include `set.h` in this source file.

Comment: Glad to know it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
#define tree
```

and later in the same file:

```
int get_number_of_leaves(Tree *tree);
```

So `tree` is both a macro name and a variable.  Not surprising that you receive errors!

Thats why macro names should not contain small characters, never.